# Shaka Player does not trigger "error listener"

Tags: javascript, webos, shaka

I am using ShakaPlayer in my WebOS Project.

I implemented same thing in the documentation,like the one below.

```
player.addEventListener('error', function(event){
    console.log("errror",event)
});
```

but i did not get any console.log for the error instead i always get error in uncaught(in promise).

output error image

[image: 1]

> shaka-player.ui.js:24
> Uncaught (in promise) ve {severity: 2, category: 6, code: 6001, data: Array(0), handled: false}

i tried the same thing in documentation and i expected that i can console.log the error
and keep it for my usage.

Somehow the result is still the same , there is no error listener trigger and still the
error is in uncaught error.

Comment: https://github.com/shaka-project/shaka-player/blob/main/docs/tutorials/errors.md

Comment: Can you add a code snippet with more info?